# ViewState["sample"] Variable not retaining value on postback in a composite control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, composite

I have created a composite control with sample details as follows. Basically, the first time on page load the control sets a view state variable and the problem is that on post back (when the button is clicked), the ViewState variable is null. I have researched extensively and I am not able to find a solution. I checked all the Microsoft recommended articles and also from other developers. This approach seem to work for everyone and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

PS: This code may not work as it is only for illustrative purposes. but this is exactly what i'm doing in my code.

```
Public class Test : CompositeControl
{
    private Button btnTest = new Button();
    public string TestViewState
    {
        get
        {
            string s = (string)ViewState["test"];
            return (s == null) ? String.Empty : s;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["test"] = value;
        }
    }

    private void set()
    {
        TestViewState = "test";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            set();  
    }

    protected override void RecreateChildControls()
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
         base.Controls.Clear();  
         btnTest.ID = "btnTest";
         btnTest.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmitTest_Click);

         if (!ChildControlsCreated)
         Controls.Add(btnTest);      

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        btnSumbit.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void btnSubmitTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = TestViewState; // Viewstate value is null here!!!!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this control is called from another composite control.. may be the child control data is not held in viewstate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that Page_Load is getting called? As far as I can remember that "notation" works only on pages and User Controls (didn't check that). Try overriding:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Test it with a Debugger.

Comment: Yes, it is getting called. Actually the page_load is being called from the page where this control is. I put it in here for display purposes. I have also verified that the page_load works from within the control as well.. I made a mistake in saying that this custom control is a child of another one. Actually, this is being used straight from an aspx page.

Comment: I've Tested your code now with an ASP.NET WebSite. Page_Load has **NOT** been called, OnLoad(...) was called. When moving set() to OnLoad(...) everything works fine

Comment: ok, it seems to work when I tried with this code, even with page load (in the actual page)..so, it must be something on my actual control... i'll look into it further. Thanks for checking that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the enableviewstate was disabled at the web.config level by another team member. Glad I found it. Thanks Arthur for confirming it worked for you.

Comment: Oh - one of those "nice" bugs ;-)